# Update property values using Dependency Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have two classes in my scenario (say A and B) wherein I create an instance of class B in class A. Both have a property named Settings. Whenever the value of the Settings property of class B is updated, I need it to immediately update the value of the Settings property of class A. I have read that I can do so using `DependencyProperty` but I'm struggling at the moment.

Here's the class structure:

```
    public class A
    {
        public Settings Settings { get; set; }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public Settings Settings { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Settings
    {
        Hidden,
        Visible
    }
```

Here's my attempt at implementing dependency properties.

```
public class A : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SettingsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Settings", typeof(Settings), typeof(A),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Settings.Visible, new PropertyChangedCallback(SettingsChanged)));

    public Settings Settings
    {
        get { return (Settings)GetValue(SettingsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SettingsProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void SettingsChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Update the Settings property of class B
    }
}

public class B : DependencyObject
{
    public static DependencyProperty SettingsProperty;
    public Settings Settings
    {
        get
        {
            return (Settings)GetValue(SettingsProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SettingsProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

However, i can't seem to get it to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could create a Binding between the two Settings properties. The Binding could even be two-way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the primary issue is that dependency properties are declared in/for the class which does not inherit DependencyObject

> A class which defines a dependency property must be inherited from the DependencyObject class. Many of the UI controls class which are used in XAML are derived from the DependencyObject class and they support dependency properties, e.g. Button class supports the IsMouseOver dependency property.

check this link for more info on [WPF - Dependency Properties](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_dependency_properties.htm)

Comment: I am in fact inheriting the classes from DependencyObject. I just missed adding them in code snippet. Updated now.

Comment: @RahulVijayDawda in this case, a small sample project could help to get a better visibility on the issue. Could you produce a workable sample project which can reproduce the issue and provide it for review?